# multisites with one login page

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on

I have a site with login page and also have other sites in another host.
I want another sites also have login page to first site and when users try to login, them redirect to first site and automate login. do you think I must send user and pass as parameter to first login url? what is the best way?
sites is written with asp.net and web server is iis 7.

Answer (score 0):

Make a central class, which you can compile into a dll, this class will be used to do the authentication.  just reference the dll in your websites that want to use the same logon method.